# After element expand the window width

Tags: html, css

I have a slider and I want to put a skewed div to the left and the right of the image, so I used `before` and `after` but I have an issue. With the after element it expands the window width, I mean, the window takes larger than 100% due to the after element. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5o7qbyhm/2/)

```
.slides{
  margin-top:40px;
  position:relative;
  padding:0;
  width:85%;
}
.slides::before{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -9%;
  width:17%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:white;
  content: "";
  color: blue;
  transform: skew(-27deg);
}
.slides::after{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -9%;
  width:17%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:white;
  content: "";
  color: blue;
  transform: skew(-27deg);
}
.slides li img{
  width:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="slides">
     <li style="display: block; width: 100%;" class="slide-21 ms-image"><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/1680x560/" alt="" class="slider-19 slide-21" /></li>
 </ul>
```

How can I do to make the slider 100% width without having the after element outside the window width ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does using `overflow:hidden` on `.slides` work?

https://jsfiddle.net/4jdvjf8p/